# Is there a developer API for Agile Accelerator?

Tags: documentation

I'd like to integrate into a Node.js app and from my research it seems there's no dev support for this Salesforce feature but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agile Accelerator isn't a Salesforce feature as such - it's a [managed package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000ps3jEAA) from Salesforce Labs.

As such, you can interact with its objects using the normal [Salesforce REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_working_with_records.htm) for manipulating records, provided you have the appropriate CRUD and FLS access.

If you install the application in an org (including a sandbox) you'll be able to look through the list of installed components in Setup. According to the AppExchange, Agile Accelerator includes 100 custom objects.